# Launching Safari on iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to Open a Link without displaying the Safari? I mean it runs on hide.

This is my code.

```
NSString *WebURL = @"http://cvbn-dev.fgrhjnd.com/register.php";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WebURL]];
```

Comment: What do you mean by open a link without displaying the safari and runs on hide? Are you looking for a webView ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display the website, you should use a webview. If by "on hide" you mean that you do not want to display the website but merely to get its contents, you should use NSURL (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i ) or CFNetwork (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH4-SW10).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your method:

```
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://myurl.com";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[WebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  check the your URL.

I checked but **Your URL is not valid.**

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to show a web page and allow your user to register (but without launching Safari), or if you want to collect the data and register your user in the background, without showing the page.  Both are possible, but require quite different solutions.  The WebView code in Rajneesh071's answer is a good place to start for the former, but you need to be aware that if you ever follow a link in the web application, you will likely launch Safari as a result.  You need to use something like window.location = 'newUrl' in your javascript to change pages.

If you are looking for the latter, start with code that looks something like this:

```
NSURL* url = <create your URL>;
NSString* postVariables = <post data in form format>;
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

request.HTTPBody = [postVariables dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* pResponse, 
                                                      NSData* pData, 
                                                    NSError* pError) 
{ <Process the response> }
```